# Running bundle exec in eclipse

Tags: ruby, eclipse, exec, bundler, watir-webdriver

Can anyone please help me with steps to run bundle exec in eclipse IDE. Here is the command I am trying to execute via eclipse

```
bundle exec rspec -I . spec/test_run_202_spec.rb
```

but I am currently getting error message stating when i kick off above command using external tool configuration

```
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run 'gem install bundler' first.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It's a problem for color support.

Some applications need a specific TERM setting to support color.

I had an alike problem with bash script called by compiler in eclipse.
I found more infomation in this [**link**](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/6.1/postlfs/profile.html).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to get a ruby devkit installed first, then bundler. Try following steps here: https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit